# hidding a line of text until game is compleate

Tags: javascript, html

I have a maze game ( making player and end goal later) and im trying to make a span that will show up once the game is completed. so far its doing nothing.

Ive tried this

```
var mazeComplete  = document.getElementById("mazeComplete");
    var gameComplete = false;

function checkGameFinished() {

    if(gameComplete = false){
     mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    } else if (gameComplete = true) {
     mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'visible'

     }
}
```

but with all my code its not working at all. just wanted to see if i could hide the text.

html:

```
<head>
<title>Maze</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mazegenerator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Maze.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#maze {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#maze td {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
canvas {
position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="maze">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>


<script>
    var disp = newMaze(20,20);
    for (var i = 0; i < disp.length; i++) {
        $('#maze > tbody').append("");
        for (var j = 0; j < disp[i].length; j++) {
            var selector = i+"-"+j;
            $('#maze > tbody').append("<td id='"+selector+"'>&nbsp;</td>");
            if (disp[i][j][0] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-top', '2px solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][1] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-right', '2px solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][2] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-bottom', '2px solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][3] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-left', '2px solid black'); }
        }
        $('#maze > tbody').append("");
    }
</script>
    <br>
    <span id="mazeComplete">Maze complete &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button id="resetMaze" onclick="mazeReset()">New Maze</button> </span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Completed&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="mazeCompletions">0</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function newMaze(x, y) {

    // Establish variables and starting grid
    var totalCells = x*y;
    var cells = new Array();
    var unvis = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        cells[i] = new Array();
        unvis[i] = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = [0,0,0,0];
            unvis[i][j] = true;
        }
    }

    // Set a random position to start from
    var currentCell = [Math.floor(Math.random()*y), Math.floor(Math.random()*x)];
    var path = [currentCell];
    unvis[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]] = false;
    var visited = 1;

    // Loop through all available cell positions
    while (visited < totalCells) {
        // Determine neighboring cells
        var pot = [[currentCell[0]-1, currentCell[1], 0, 2],
                [currentCell[0], currentCell[1]+1, 1, 3],
                [currentCell[0]+1, currentCell[1], 2, 0],
                [currentCell[0], currentCell[1]-1, 3, 1]];
        var neighbors = new Array();

        // Determine if each neighboring cell is in game grid, and whether it has already been checked
        for (var l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
            if (pot[l][0] > -1 && pot[l][0] < y && pot[l][1] > -1 && pot[l][1] < x && unvis[pot[l][0]][pot[l][1]]) { neighbors.push(pot[l]); }
        }

        // If at least one active neighboring cell has been found
        if (neighbors.length) {
            // Choose one of the neighbors at random
            next = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random()*neighbors.length)];

            // Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen neighboring cell
            cells[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]][next[2]] = 1;
            cells[next[0]][next[1]][next[3]] = 1;

            // Mark the neighbor as visited, and set it as the current cell
            unvis[next[0]][next[1]] = false;
            visited++;
            currentCell = [next[0], next[1]];
            path.push(currentCell);
        }
        // Otherwise go back up a step and keep going
        else {
            currentCell = path.pop();
        }
    }
    return cells;
}

function mazeReset(){
   document.location.reload() 
}









var mazeComplete  = document.getElementById("mazeComplete");
var gameComplete = false;

function checkGameFinished() {

    if(gameComplete = false){
     mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    } else if (gameComplete = true) {
     mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'visible'

     }
}
```

I expect when game is launched for

`<span id="mazeComplete">Maze complete &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button id="resetMaze" onclick="mazeReset()">New Maze</button> </span>`

to be hidden until gamecomplete becomes true. but at the moment its not hidden at all.

js fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pma17sfq/3/

Comment: I don't see anything that calls `checkGameFinished()`.

Comment: Also, your `if` statement is wrong: `gameComplete = false` is assignment; you want comparison, which is `gameComplete === false`

Comment: Also, checking equality is done with two or three equals signs, not one. `a=b` will *assign* the value of b into the variable a, and then returns the value. `a==b` checks if a and b are equal in value, and returns true or false. `a===b` checks if a and b are equal in both value AND type (i.e. both numbers, both strings, etc.), and returns true or false. *EDIT* Ninja'd by @Herohtar :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. You are never calling `checkGameFinished()`, so the check and the hiding are never performed
2. By the time your script is executed, the element `#mazeComplete` does not exist yet. Move your script to the end of the body.
3. In your if conditions, `gameComplete = false` and `gameComplete = true` are not *comparing* the value, but *setting* it! Change the operator to `===` to perform a type-safe comparison.

```js
var disp = newMaze(20, 20);
for (var i = 0; i < disp.length; i++) {
  $('#maze > tbody').append("<tr>");
  for (var j = 0; j < disp[i].length; j++) {
    var selector = i + "-" + j;
    $('#maze > tbody').append("<td id='" + selector + "'>&nbsp;</td>");
    if (disp[i][j][0] == 0) {
      $('#' + selector).css('border-top', '2px solid black');
    }
    if (disp[i][j][1] == 0) {
      $('#' + selector).css('border-right', '2px solid black');
    }
    if (disp[i][j][2] == 0) {
      $('#' + selector).css('border-bottom', '2px solid black');
    }
    if (disp[i][j][3] == 0) {
      $('#' + selector).css('border-left', '2px solid black');
    }
  }
  $('#maze > tbody').append("<tr>");
}



function newMaze(x, y) {

  // Establish variables and starting grid
  var totalCells = x * y;
  var cells = new Array();
  var unvis = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    cells[i] = new Array();
    unvis[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
      cells[i][j] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
      unvis[i][j] = true;
    }
  }

  // Set a random position to start from
  var currentCell = [Math.floor(Math.random() * y), Math.floor(Math.random() * x)];
  var path = [currentCell];
  unvis[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]] = false;
  var visited = 1;

  // Loop through all available cell positions
  while (visited < totalCells) {
    // Determine neighboring cells
    var pot = [
      [currentCell[0] - 1, currentCell[1], 0, 2],
      [currentCell[0], currentCell[1] + 1, 1, 3],
      [currentCell[0] + 1, currentCell[1], 2, 0],
      [currentCell[0], currentCell[1] - 1, 3, 1]
    ];
    var neighbors = new Array();

    // Determine if each neighboring cell is in game grid, and whether it has already been checked
    for (var l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
      if (pot[l][0] > -1 && pot[l][0] < y && pot[l][1] > -1 && pot[l][1] < x && unvis[pot[l][0]][pot[l][1]]) {
        neighbors.push(pot[l]);
      }
    }

    // If at least one active neighboring cell has been found
    if (neighbors.length) {
      // Choose one of the neighbors at random
      next = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)];

      // Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen neighboring cell
      cells[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]][next[2]] = 1;
      cells[next[0]][next[1]][next[3]] = 1;

      // Mark the neighbor as visited, and set it as the current cell
      unvis[next[0]][next[1]] = false;
      visited++;
      currentCell = [next[0], next[1]];
      path.push(currentCell);
    }
    // Otherwise go back up a step and keep going
    else {
      currentCell = path.pop();
    }
  }
  return cells;
}

function mazeReset() {
  document.location.reload()
}



var gameComplete = false;
var mazeComplete = document.getElementById("mazeComplete");


function checkGameFinished() {

  if (gameComplete === false) {
    mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  } else if (gameComplete === true) {
    mazeComplete.style.visibility = 'visible'

  }
}

checkGameFinished();
```

```css
#maze {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#maze td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="maze">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<br>
<span id="mazeComplete">Maze complete &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button id="resetMaze" onclick="mazeReset()">New Maze</button> </span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Completed&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="mazeCompletions">0</span>
```

Comment: i forgot to add back that i tried calling the function . i should of commented it out. im grateful for what you gave me thanks. i had examples of like 1 tiny bit of span being hidden but not a whole line with a button in it. I deleted my try on calling the function.

Comment: from yours it broke my reset button. how do i make a function that recreates the maze on click. i currently have just a button that refreshes the page

Comment: When I set `gameComplete = true` in my snippet in order to display the button, it works fine for me and generates a new maze on click

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Constantin in general but your most "immediate" problem you have, where "the span is always visible" is because, in your fiddle at least, the `<span>` is not hidden at start.. you have to make it like:

```
 `<span hidden id="mazeComplete">`
```

Then later on when the time comes you will set its visibility property like you do.